# Google plus deprecation, Does already implemented OAuth 2.0 based sign in flow do required major changes?

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, google-plus, deprecated

Relevant stackoverflow ticket: [signin for server-side apps and plus deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54427328/signin-for-server-side-apps-and-plus-deprecation)

As mentioned in above stackoverflow question by David, We also have already implemented google sign in with OAuth 2.0 based flow, we are not passing any scope details & after google authentication
when return back to our site it seems adding additional scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me and might be due to this we also get this deprecation notification.

sample scope return from google after OAuth 2.0 authentication:
scope=openid email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me

So our question is:

Q1: Does OAuth 2.0 flow work fine after this google plus deprecation?

Q2: Do we required to change scope instead of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me need to use anything else to make it working as it is after plush deprecation with same code and flow with OAuth 2.0, if so any suggestion how we can override scope in OAuth 2.0 to not forcefully apply https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me might be from google.

Q3:  Including the plus.me which is we guess what I'm concerned about. How do we control or stop this? Or maybe We don't need to do anything and Google will take care of it themselves before they shutdown the plus.me scope? [As mentioned David in above relevant question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been some confusion, but to try and answer your questions

**Does OAuth 2.0 work after Google+ Shutdown**

Yes.

Google's OAuth shouldn't be dependent on Google+ at all, although some assumptions do make it [look that way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54435567/1405634).

If you're using OAuth 2.0 with non-plus scopes and non-plus methods, you're fine.

**Do we need to change the plus.me scope?**

Yes. If you are explicitly requesting the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`, then you will need to remove this scope from your requests.

If you, and your libraries, are **not** explicitly asking for this scope - then you're good.

**What about Google including the plus.me scope?**

You don't need to worry about this. As they said in their corrected email

> The email listed that one or more of your projects are requesting the
>   “plus.me” scope, and would thus be affected. We would like to clarify
>   that only **projects *directly* requesting the “plus.me” scope are
>   affected**. This scope may have been listed in some emails, even if not
>   directly requested by your project. We apologize for any confusion
>   caused.

So you just need to make sure that you aren't explicitly requesting the scope.